# google repo tool to have two git remote

Tags: android, gerrit

I want to sync code from different remotes to reduce server's loading.

1. Two remotes(remote1, remote2) in the manifest.
2. gerrit code-review is still through remote1.

Therefore, I have to upload changes to remote1, and sync code from remote1 and remote2.

Is it possible to have remote1 in every git project after running repo sync command?
I do not want to run "repo forall -c "git remote add remote1 xxxxx" command.

Thanks a lot

Comment: So... you already list the two remotes in the manifest like the first numbered bullet says? Or is that just describing the desired state? And what's the point of having both remotes in the manifest? So that people can choose which one to download from? If server load balancing is your ultimate goal I think you're barking up the wrong tree. If you instead set up an A record in DNS that points to both servers (and list this name as the remote in the manifest), clients will distribute the load reasonably evenly.

Comment: I have two servers to sync code.
But code-review is only on server1.
So I want to know if there is any way that I can have remote1 in every git repo.

Comment: The server used for code reviews is configured completely separately from the server used for fetches. It sounds like you should just list remote1 in the manifest's `<remote>` tag.

Comment: I add remote2 in manifest, Is it possible to modify repo tool?

Comment: Of course, but nothing so far suggests that you have to touch the Repo source code. As I said earlier, if your goal is to distribute the Git downloads between two servers you can use DNS or a load-balancing frontend. Having two remotes in each manifest is a bad way of solving this particular problem. I suggest you edit your question and clarify exactly what fundamental problem you're trying to solve. "How do I add a remote to each git" is not a problem, it's a solution to some other underlying problem.